# data processing query (perl)

Tags: perl

I have data something like below:

sample 1:

```
my $data = [
[16, 63, 66, 67, 68], 
[16, 63, 66, 67, 68], 
[16, 18, 61, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68],
[61, 62, 66, 67],
[62, 65, 66, 67],
[62, 65, 66, 67],
[66, 67],
[66, 67],
];
```

I would like to turn this into something like below:

```
[
   [66,67],
   [66,67],
   [66,67],
   [66,67],
   [66,67],
   [66,67],
   [66,67],
   [66,67],
]
```

Another case as below:

sample 2:

```
my $data = [
    [1,2,3],
    [2,4],
    [4,3],
    [4],
    ];

into

[
    [2], 
    [2,4],
    [4],
    [4],
]
```

Rules:

> 1) Find common number(s) in all cells, if found, assign them to each cell (sample 1).
>
> 2) If two consecutive cells have a common then assign the common
>   number to  both cells (sample 2).
>
> 3) Two consecutive cells will always have one common number.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. To answer the question as stated may take a significant amount of effort. You need to show some effort into solving the problem yourself before you can expect much assistance from us. Please explain what methods you have tried and describe how well they worked. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as being too vague and not providing enough information about what you have tried. See also the help link (at the top of this page) about what sort of question can be asked here on Stack overflow.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what the output should be for `[ [1, 2], [2, 1] ]`, i.e. how to order the numbers.

Comment: numbering order is not important. for this [ [1, 2], [2, 1] ], I would expect the same result [ [1, 2], [2, 1] ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find common numbers, use hashes. To produce unique numbers, use hashes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More;

sub process {
    my $data = shift;
    my %c;
    for my $i (0 .. $#$data) {
        for my $m (@{ $data->[$i] }) {
            undef $c{$m}{$i};
        }
    }

    my @common = sort { $a <=> $b }
                 grep @$data == keys %{ $c{$_} },
                 keys %c;

    return [ map [@common], @$data ] if @common;

    my %r;
    for my $i (0 .. $#$data - 1) {
        for my $m (@{ $data->[$i] }) {
            if (exists $c{$m}{ $i + 1 }) {
                undef $r{$_}{$m} for $i, $i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return [ map [ sort { $a <=> $b }
                   keys %{ $r{$_} } ],
             sort { $a <=> $b } keys %r
           ]
}

my @expected = ([
                 [66,67],
                 [66,67],
                 [66,67],
                 [66,67],
                 [66,67],
                 [66,67],
                 [66,67],
                 [66,67],
                ],
                [
                 [2],
                 [2,4],
                 [4],
                 [4],
                ],
               );

for my $data ([
               [16, 63, 66, 67, 68],
               [16, 63, 66, 67, 68],
               [16, 18, 61, 62, 63, 66, 67, 68],
               [61, 62, 66, 67],
               [62, 65, 66, 67],
               [62, 65, 66, 67],
               [66, 67],
               [66, 67],
              ],
              [
               [1,2,3],
               [2,4],
               [4,3],
               [4],
              ],
             ) {
    is_deeply(process($data), shift @expected);
}

done_testing();
```